# 'Table' doesnt format nicely when trying to print array in C++

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to print out a table nicely with even padding like so:

```
int rowLength = 8 * 4 + 8 + 1;
char arr[rowLength];

fill(arr, arr + rowLength, '-');
string divider = arr;

for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
    cout << "\n" << divider << "\n";
    for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
        cout << "|  " << "1";
        if(x == 7)
            cout << "|";
    }
}
cout << "\n" << divider;
```

And I'm expecting the table to print evenly, however it prints as follows:

[image: Image 1]

Does anyone know how I can fix the print code, so it evenly prints and without the 2h at the end?

Thanks!

Comment: Edited: added divider code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string divider = arr;
```

This `std::string` gets constructed from `arr`, which is a `char` array that gets decayed to a `char *`. When constructing from a `char *`, the `char *` must be a null-terminated string.

Your code fills the entire `char` array with characters, but fails to append an additional `'\0'` byte. This results in undefined behavior.